# Extract array members to set method via jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use this method: https://editor.datatables.net/reference/api/field().update() but I use an array which I got from an ajax call and so need to extract the array members to set this update method with. Any idea how this can be done? Many thanks.

```
var flags = ['USA','Brazil','Germany','Canada'];
editor.field('GroupName').update( [
    $.each(flags, function(key, value) {
        var yourkey = key + 1;
    })
] );
```

This returns a single string with all flags whereas I need each flag extracted separately.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is returning a single string as you say, as `$.each()` does not return anything.  So you are passing update `[undefined]`  EDIT: Nvm, it returns the object iterated over, so you're passing in `[['USA', 'Brazil', 'Germany', 'Canada']]`

Comment: The linked-to API details are hidden behind a pay-wall.

Comment: Sorry I think I pasted the code incorrectly. Here's the correct code:
                    editor.field('GroupName').update( [
                        $.each(flags, function(key, value) {
                            var yourkey = key + 1;
                        })
                    ] );

Comment: I don't think the update method matters much. The method normally expects this: 

editor.field('GroupName').update( [
'USA','Brazil','Germany','Canada'
] );

But I can only work with arrays. So how can I convert an array to a list of its members like the method expects?

Comment: The below code: editor.field('GroupName').update( [
    flags
] ); gives the same result as the code above, ie a string of the flags in one select option rather than each array member is its own select option

Comment: @freedomn-m  wrong api reference.  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each

Comment: @MikeG001 `flags` is already an array, so why are you trying to put an array in another array?

Comment: @Taplar a) d'oh b) same callback signature so still adding the `indexInArray` not the `key` and still doing nothing with it so returns the original array untouched.

Comment: @MikeG001 did you try: `editor.field('GroupName').update( flags );` ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simply to remove the square brackets

editor.field('GroupName').update(
    flags
);